# What do reviewers see when I flag an answer?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged an answer today as not an answer. The answer was asking a question to the OP.

20 minutes later the answer was completely redone and is now an answer. Will the reviewer of my flag see the answer as it was when I flagged it, or in its current state.

To my knowledge I cannot retract the flag and as I stated it is now an answer

Comment: You can retract the flag if it hasn't been resolved at the time.

Comment: Reviewers always see the current state of the post.

Comment: The help section on flagging has the answer about retracting flags: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts .

Comment: thanks guys, I found the retract button and its good know that they see the current state!

Answer (score 5):

There are two kind of "reviewers" that could see post due to that flag: regular reviewers and moderators.

- regular reviewers see post in its current state without any information how the post got into that particular review queue. It is very likely updated post will be considered an answer and your flag "disputed". Reviewers can check history too, but it should not have impact on whether currently post is an answer or not.
- moderators will see the post in its current state and the flag. As result they may want to spend some time on checking if you are flagging correctly. Likely they'd check post history when you flagged the post or even your flagging history to see if you are flagging posts correctly in general. I *believe* they can manually set outcome for flag {declined, disputed, useful} even if current state of the post is no longer NAA.

If you found out that flag no longer applies you can retract it as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts, but I'm not sure if post will be removed from review queue at that point. I would not worry too much about some NAA/VLQ flags becoming invalid (unless you find yourself with getting significant portion of your flags declined/disputed and being close to lose flagging privileges).

Comment: Do diamond mods actually bother investigating odd flags as you suggest, or do they most of the time just decline and let it go? I believe it's more the latter. (Also, I *know* mods can't dispute flags except spam/abusive flags, although they can change helpfulness of a flag after the fact in certain cases.)